# Branching strategy for major redesign

Tags: version-control, branching-and-merging

I'm wondering what the best branching strategy is for this scenario.  My company is planning a major rewrite of their web application that will change about 50% of the code and may take a few months.  While, this development is taking place, we will also need to do smaller enhancements to the current version of the app.

I was thinking about developing the rewrite on trunk and creating a branch for the current version.  As we need to make changes to the current version, we make them on the branch and then merge them into trunk.  After the rewrite is complete, it will already have all the changes from the branch merged into it, so it will be ready to be released.  Any opinion on whether this is a good strategy, or if there is a better one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are refactoring the current application over a few months time, and release it in one big bang, you will probably have an application that still contains lots of unused code, bad code, and doesn't do exactly what you (will then) want it to do.

If you do want to go on with a single large project that will be released big bang in half a year, you'd better start from scratch and copy only the pieces you really can use. Any fixes and enhancements to the current app will have to be made to the new app too, although they may be solved in a different way. You probably can still copy lots of that code though.

But the best solution: try not to enter a development trajectory of months. Refactor current code and release each refactored piece as soon as possible so it can be thoroghly tested and evaluated while you develop the next piece. If you're writing a new application, do the same thing. Start using it as quickly as possible and enhance it as you go, incorporating feedback in the final result.

Sorry I said so little about branching and merging. Yes, the way you describe is how it is often done. But no, I don't think it is the right way, because you don't want to merge fixes in old code into your new application this way.

Comment: +1, if not for answering the actual question, then for sound advice.  don't do a rewrite based on old code.  do a rewrite from scratch based on lessons learned.